# Converting AWS date string to python datetime

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datetime

I'm trying to get the AWS timestamp converted from a python string to a datetime object. The datetime format AWS provides is here 2016-09-20T17:21:14+00:00

This is the code I have that is trying to convert:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
ifile = open('text_results.txt')
reader = csv.reader(ifile)    


for row in reader:
 date_s = str(row[2])

date_o = datetime.strptime('date_s', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')
```

I don't really care about the milliseconds if there is a way to omit that since AWS doesn't even provide milliseconds, it's always 00:00. But I'm receiving the following error with this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date.py", line 15, in <module>
    date_o = datetime.strptime('date_s', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'date_s' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00'
```

Comment: Use `date_s` without quotes as in `datetime.strptime(date_s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')`

Comment: Ahh ha, that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

import csv
from datetime import datetime
ifile = open('text_results.txt')
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

for row in reader:
date_s = str(row[2])
date_o = datetime.strptime(date_s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')

kjdasdasjdas

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).